# svn+ssh: Protect repos

Tags: svn, ssh

We have several repos on a svn server running on linux using authentication with /etc/passwd (svn version 1.5). The users have access to svn via svn+ssh. All users but one are allowed to access all repos r/w. But this special user is allowed to access only one of our repos. How would you configure svn to achieve this?

As far as I know now, password file and authz file for svnserve is not able to handle this.

Thanks in advance!

Regards
Burkhard

Answer (score 0):

In the meantime I think, it's possible only with 2 groups in Linux and the appropriate rights and ownerships for files and directories within the repositories.

Regards
Burkhard